# How to find out when/who changed a BQ table column from Non Nullable to Nullable

Tags: google-bigquery

I am taking a look at a table that I created and I noticed all columns in the table are now nullable. I know I didn't do this, but I am wondering if its possible to know when this happened and who changed it.

Is there some way to find out this information?

Answer (score 3):

you can use `information_schema.jobs`.

See below query -

the `referenced_table.table_id` is the table you want to find out the change has happened
the `user_email` gives away who has made the change. NOTE: this can be a `service account` or a `user's email` too. If its a `service account`, there's every possibility that an user has `impersonated` the `service account` OR a google service like `cloud build` may have deployed the change.

Kindly also note that you will have to search the `query` column, the column can be made `not null` to `null` either by `ALTER` statement or even with `CREATE OR REPLACE` on the `table`

```
SELECT user_email, job_type,statement_type,creation_time,start_time,end_time, query,state, ref.table_id
FROM `region-australia-southeast1`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS,unnest(referenced_tables) as ref
where ref.table_id = 'newtable'
 order by creation_time desc
```

See screenshot if the query above.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What @[Bihag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20696779/bihag-kashikar) suggested is indeed a good way to achieve your use case. You can also [view job details](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs?_ga=2.6943159.-421953878.1700265584&_gac=1.127360383.1701368887.Cj0KCQiAgqGrBhDtARIsAM5s0_lZ4hbYqrmcKH0OGj39uVCjDu_u7mHqlXiGwLuDelRGi6fFntaku3caAscwEALw_wcB#view_job_details_2) in your Project History and explore events or actions through your [Logs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring#logs).

> BigQuery saves a six-month job history for all the jobs of a project.

> The job history includes jobs that are in the RUNNING state and jobs that are DONE (indicated by reporting the state as SUCCESS or FAILURE).

Adding this [JOBS view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs) document for more information.